# lateinit property ApplicationContext has not been initialized

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hello I relatively new to the programming world and I'm having a problem with my project.
I have a simple counter that counts how many birds you saw and then changes the color of the TextView (that displays counter) depending on what button you pressed.
I'm using viewModel with live data and data binding for this and it works. Now when I try to add Shared Preferences to store my data so that they can survive application being shut down. When I try to use 'userDataProvider' I get a error that I dont know how to fix.

//Error
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property ApplicationContext has not been initialized
at com.example.lv4_birdscounter.BirdsCounterApp$Companion.getApplicationContext(BirdsCounterApp.kt:11)
at com.example.lv4_birdscounter.PrefsManager.setCounter(PrefsManager.kt:53)
at com.example.lv4_birdscounter.PrefsManager.setBirdCounter(PrefsManager.kt:19)
at com.example.lv4_birdscounter.BirdsCounter.onCreate(BirdsCounter.kt:52)

//BirdsCounter.kt

```
package com.example.lv4_birdscounter

import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.lv4_birdscounter.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


class BirdsCounter : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    lateinit var viewModel: BirdsCounterViewModel

    private val userDataProvider: UserDataProvider by lazy { PrefsManager }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BirdsCounterViewModel::class.java)


        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main).apply {
            this.setLifecycleOwner(this@BirdsCounter)
            this.viewmodel=viewModel
        }


        viewModel.birdsSeen.observe(this, Observer {
            //display new data
            binding.tvCounter.text = it.toString()
        })

        viewModel.birdsColor.observe(this, Observer {
            //display new data
            binding.tvCounter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(it))

            //Make number more visible by changing the colour of the text
            when(it){
                viewModel.GREEN -> binding.tvCounter.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                viewModel.WHITE -> binding.tvCounter.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                else -> binding.tvCounter.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            }
        })

        //Crashes
        userDataProvider.birdCounter = 5

        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

}
```

//BirdsCounterApp.kt

```
codpackage com.example.lv4_birdscounter

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context

class BirdsCounterApp : Application(){

    companion object {
        lateinit var ApplicationContext: Context
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ApplicationContext = this
    }


}
```

//PrefsManager.kt

```
    package com.example.lv4_birdscounter

import android.content.Context

interface UserDataProvider{
    var birdCounter: Int
    var tvColor: String
}


object PrefsManager: UserDataProvider{

    private val PREFS_FILE = "preferences"
    private val COUNTER_ID = "counter_id"
    private val COLOR_ID = "color_id"

    override var birdCounter: Int
        get() = getCounter()
        set(value) = setCounter(value)

    override var tvColor: String
        get() = getColor()
        set(value) = setColor(value)


    //for color
    private fun getColor(): String {
        return BirdsCounterApp.ApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFS_FILE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        ).getString(COLOR_ID, "#4A6572")?: "#4A6572"
    }

    private fun setColor(value: String){
        BirdsCounterApp.ApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFS_FILE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString(COLOR_ID, value)
                .apply()
    }


    //for counter
    private fun getCounter(): Int {
        return BirdsCounterApp.ApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFS_FILE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        ).getInt(COUNTER_ID, 0)?:0
    }

    private fun setCounter(value: Int){
        BirdsCounterApp.ApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFS_FILE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit() // dobivamo Editor instancu koja se koristi za izmjenu SharedPreferences-a
                .putInt(COUNTER_ID, value)
                .apply() // pohranjujemo promjene
    }
}
```

//BirdsCounterViewModel

```
    package com.example.lv4_birdscounter

import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel



class BirdsCounterViewModel() : ViewModel() {


    val RED = "#D82929"
    val BLUE = "#2121E1"
    val WHITE = "#FFFFFFFF"
    val GREEN = "#2DF62D"
    val LIGHT_GRAY = "#4A6572"

    private val _birdsSeen: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    val birdsSeen: LiveData<Int> = _birdsSeen

    private val _birdsColor: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>("#4A6572")
    val birdsColor: LiveData<String> = _birdsColor

    fun onButtonPressed(color: String){
        _birdsSeen.value?.let { _birdsSeen.postValue(it + 1) }
        _birdsColor.value?.let { _birdsColor.postValue(color) }
    }

    fun onResetButtonPressed(){
        _birdsSeen.value?.let { _birdsSeen.postValue(0) }
        _birdsColor.value?.let { _birdsColor.postValue(LIGHT_GRAY) }
    }


}
```

//mainActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.lv4_birdscounter.BirdsCounterViewModel" />

    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray"
        tools:context=".BirdsCounter">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guide_vertical_center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCounter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="@dimen/tvMargin"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:textSize="@dimen/tvTextSize"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="@string/tvCounterDefaultValue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRed"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="@dimen/btnMargin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
            android:text="@string/btnRedText"

            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guide_vertical_center"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvCounter"
            app:strokeColor="@color/black"

            app:strokeWidth="@dimen/btnStrokeWidth"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewmodel.onButtonPressed(viewmodel.RED)}"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBlue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="@dimen/btnMargin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
            android:text="@string/btnBlueText"

            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guide_vertical_center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvCounter"
            app:strokeColor="@color/black"

            app:strokeWidth="@dimen/btnStrokeWidth"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewmodel.onButtonPressed(viewmodel.BLUE)}"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWhite"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="@dimen/btnMargin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/btnWhiteText"

            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guide_vertical_center"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnRed"
            app:strokeColor="@color/black"

            app:strokeWidth="@dimen/btnStrokeWidth"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewmodel.onButtonPressed(viewmodel.WHITE)}"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGreen"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_margin="@dimen/btnMargin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
            android:text="@string/btnGreenText"

            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guide_vertical_center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnBlue"
            app:strokeColor="@color/black"

            app:strokeWidth="@dimen/btnStrokeWidth"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewmodel.onButtonPressed(viewmodel.GREEN)}"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:text="@string/btnResetText"

            android:textColor="@color/white"


            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guide_vertical_center"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guide_vertical_center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnWhite"

            android:onClick="@{()->viewmodel.onResetButtonPressed()}"
            />





    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to initialise the ApplicationContext in your application class. Android will provide it for you. You just need to access it from where ever you need. ApplicationContext is basically an instance that is singleton and can be accessed in activity via getApplicationContext(). This context is tied to the lifecycle of an application.

And rather than accessing the application context via companion object. Inject the context to the respective file where it needs to be used via constructor and use that instance. You can also use dependency injection libraries like Dagger to help you inject dependencies.

You could do something like PrefsManager constructor (val context:Context)
to do constructor injection of context manually from your birds counter activity into PrefsManager and then use that context to save to sharedpreferences

Comment: Thank you for you answer I didn't add BirdsCounterApp to manifest....

 -- android:name=".BirdsCounterApp" -- 
This line of code was all I needed